# React-router: How to enter direct path without using Link

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have a small react app.
in the app, I have a login form.

I have 3 pages as seen in the router at `App` component below.
The issue is that I can't access any URL beside the `/` path.
If I try to enter `/login` or `/mechinasetup` I receive 404 error.

Now, in localhost it works great, I can enter all the paths but on the server, I can enter only to `/` path.

If I enter a `Link` to the main page it will take me to the login page.
I don't want to add to the main page a link to the login page, I want the user to be able to see the `/login` by typing `/login`.

in the `login`  and `MechinaSetup` components I have a redirect script that checks the local storage and according to the value there it will redirect the user if needed (code below).

How can I to this redirect without using `<Link>`?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter , Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Calc from './components/Calc';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import MechinaSetup from './components/adminarea/MechinaSetup';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter basename="/calc">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Calc}  />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/mechinasetup" component={MechinaSetup} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in short, this is the function that should redirect the login page

```
  redirectUser = auth => {
    if (auth === false) {
      this.props.history.push("/login");
    }
  };
```

I am using `history.push` as suggested in this question:
[Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router?rq=1)

**entire components**

login component - the redirect function called **redirectUser**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import { userLogedIn } from '../../actions'; 
import {
    Button,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    Col,
    Checkbox,
    ControlLabel,
    HelpBlock,
    Container,
    Row
} from 'react-bootstrap';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    state={
        username: '',
        password: '',
        data: [],
        auth: false
    }

    componentWillMount(){
       const auth = localStorage.getItem('auth');

       localStorage.getItem('auth') === 'true' ? 
       this.props.userLogedIn(this.props): console.log('xxx');
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.redirectUser(this.props.user.auth);
     }

    onSubmitLogin = (event) => {
        // let auth = this.state.auth;

        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('./api/user_switch/' + this.state.username + 
        '/'+ this.state.password )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            if(json.count > 0)
            {
                this.props.userLogedIn(this.props)

            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('parsing faild', error))

    }

    onChange(event){
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    redirectUser = (auth) =>{
        if(auth === true){
            localStorage.setItem('auth', true);
            localStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);
            localStorage.setItem('password', this.state.password);
            this.props.history.push("/mechinasetup");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container id="LoginForm" className="align-middle" style={loginForm}>
            <h1 className="text-center">כניסה לניהול מחשבון מכינה</h1>
                <Row className="show-grid justify-content-center">
                    <Col xs={8}>
                        <Form>
                            <FormGroup  controlId="formHorizontalusername">
                                    <Col xs={12} componentclass={'aa'} className="text-right">
                                        דואר אלקטרוני:
                                    </Col>

                                    <Col xs={12}>
                                    <FormControl 
                                        ref="username" 
                                        name="username" 
                                        type="text" 
                                        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} 
                                        placeholder="הקלד דואר אלקטרוני"/>

                                    </Col>

                                </FormGroup>
                                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword" >
                                    <Col xs={12} componentclass={'cc'} className="text-right">
                                        סיסמא:
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col xs={12}>
                                    <FormControl ref="password" name="password" type="password" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} placeholder="הקלד סיסמא"/>

                                    </Col>

                                </FormGroup>
                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Col >

                                        <Button onClick={this.onSubmitLogin} type="submit" className="full-width-btn" id="loginSubmit" block>התחבר</Button>
                                    </Col>
                                </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const loginForm = {
    height: '100vh'
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        user: state.user
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        userLogedIn: (params) => dispatch(userLogedIn(params))
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

MechinaSetup Component- the redirect function called `redurectUser`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
    Container,
  Form,
  Button,
  Col,
  Row,
  Table,
  striped,
  bordered,
  hover
} from "react-bootstrap";

import { logOut, addCourse } from "../../actions";
import Courses from "./AdminCourses";
import Head from '../layout/Header';

class MechinaSetup extends Component {
  state = {
    id: Math.random(),
    courseName: '',
    courseWeeklyHours: '',
    courseType: false
  };

  redirectUser = auth => {
    if (auth === false) {
      this.props.history.push("/login");
    }
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };




  render() {
    const headerTitle = 'מחשבון מכינה';
    const Logout = true;
    return (

      <div>
        <Head headerTitle={headerTitle} isLogOut={Logout}/>

        {/* if user is not logged in redirect him to login page */}
        {this.redirectUser(this.props.user.auth)} 

        <Courses />       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
    courses: state.courses
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logOut }
)(MechinaSetup);
```

Comment: does your server backend respond with correct response for `/login` route or other route?

Answer (score 1):

I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43470639/3471458
and replace `BrowserRouter` with `HashRouter`,
now my App component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter , Route, Switch, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Calc from './components/Calc';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import MechinaSetup from './components/adminarea/MechinaSetup';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter basename="/">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Calc}  />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/mechinasetup" component={MechinaSetup} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```